# Kubuntu Problem when Installing - metalink unable to download therefore ISO

Tags: kubuntu, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wubi fails to install Kubuntu: “cannot download metalink…”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163666/wubi-fails-to-install-kubuntu-cannot-download-metalink)

I installed ubuntu with no errors, when I try to install Kubuntu using wubi.exe
I get this:

```
    An error occured:
Cannot download the metalink therefore the ISO

For more information please see the log file:
c:\users\dell\appdata\local\temp\wubi-12.04-rev265.log
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 and Higher, Use Wubi by Hakuna Matata To Install Wubi on Windows Laptop/Computers without using a USB Stick.

**Wubi Hakuna Matata download from the wiki: [https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki]**

If you want to do other Linux OS, you can use Unetbootin or Rufus

Answer (score 1):

This could be a bug. Also version of wubi and kubuntu is not mentioned in question.

Follow below steps,

1. Download kubuntu ISO → http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu
2. Download appropriate wubi version.
3. Put them in same folder.
4. Run wubi.

Answer (score 1):

Both the kubuntu download links in the installer are dead links:
http://releases.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/12.04/kubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.metalink
http://releases.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/12.04/kubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.metalink

There is a current confirmed but unassigned bug for this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1004173

- I would have thought getting hesitant Windows users to more easily try out Kubuntu would be a reasonable priority, but I suppose the priority is on Ubuntu, and that works fine.

Putting an ISO in the `wubi` folder works great in the mean time.