# Wubi fails to install Kubuntu: "cannot download metalink..."

Tags: installation, wubi

when I try to install it pops up with an error saying "cannot download metalink and therefore  the iso" and I have re-downloaded the installer multiple times and tried reinstalling multiple times. It will not work, and if you could get back to me as soon as possible that would be nice.

Comment: What installer are you downloading and from where? Usually you just download the ISO directly.

Comment: i got it from ubuntu.com

Comment: Copy/paste exact link to page or download please.

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=wubi&release=&bits=

Comment: It's a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1004173

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wubi Installer Can't Find Metalink](http://askubuntu.com/questions/202217/wubi-installer-cant-find-metalink)

Answer (score 1):

If Lubuntu, Kubuntu, Mythbuntu, etc etc is in the list of installable ISO's in Wubi, then they all should be available for installation, if neither of them (with exception to Ubuntu Desktop) is not downloadable, they should NOT be selectable in the drop down list.

Comment: This is a new bug (unrelated to the Kubuntu bug which is still not fixed) when they released 12.04.1 that stopped Wubi working with these flavours. It happened with 10.04.1 as well. You need to use the 12.04 version of wubi.exe now and that's only available on the 12.04 ISOs or here http://people.canonical.com/~evand/wubi/precise/wubi-r266-signed.exe

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be problems on your network which prevent Wubi from downloading the Kubuntu ISO on its own.

Please download the Kubuntu Desktop ISO separately from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/12.04/release/kubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso), and put `wubi.exe` in the same directory.

> Also, please take a look at this answer:
>
> [How do I get the Wubi installer to use a pre-downloaded ISO?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159524/how-do-i-get-the-wubi-installer-to-use-a-pre-downloaded-iso/159533#159533)

Then, run `wubi.exe` and it should install Kubuntu 12.04 for you

Comment: @connorhooven: if it works, please consider accepting the answer (tick/check mark on left) to close out the question as "answered". Good luck and welcome to Ubuntu/Ask Ubuntu!

Comment: Maybe you can add mention of the bug to your answer. This is a workaround to that bug

Answer (score 0):

install desktop cd from here and put it in the same file where wubi is

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/12.04/release/

edit: there is some one help you before me, good ;)