# Installation problem with metalink

Tags: boot

I am trying to install Ubuntu and  have downloaded and opened the ISO file. The installation starts nicely when I press UBI. It allows me to fill in the initial facts. But when the real program installation starts, it runs for half a second, then stops with a ping and says *Cannot download the metalink and therefore the ISO*. What does it mean and what can I do?
Sture

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wubi fails to install Kubuntu: "cannot download metalink..."](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163666/wubi-fails-to-install-kubuntu-cannot-download-metalink)

Comment: Have you also tried one of the [community supported versions](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki#releases) ?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, you are using Windows 8 or Windows 10. Wubi [official support is being phased out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi/228069#228069) and will not work with Windows versions newer than Windows 7 and Ubuntu versions newer than 15.04, at least not with official versions.

If you want to try out Ubuntu, you can run a [Live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) or you can install ubuntu [parallel to Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot).

Comment: -1 This is not true any longer. Wubi is supported by the community now.

Comment: The [Ubuntu Wiki 'wubi' entry](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) and the [Wikipedia entry on wubi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_(software)) make it appear it wasn't officially supported anymore. That's all I'm saying. OP seems to be a new Ubuntu user, so sticking to official procedures for the beginning seems reasonable. Not trying to diss wubi here, it's a great project.